# multidimensional array in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got this object:

```
var enemy = {
  'Goblin' : {
    'HP' : '20',
    'damage' : '3',
    'loot' : ['a wooden sword','a golden coin']
  },
  'row2' : {
    'key3' : 'input3',
    'key4' : 'input4'
  }
};
```

Now I want to give a `value` to the `wooden sword` but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I thought something like

```
'loot' : ['a wooden sword ' ['value' : 3] , 'a golden coin' ['value ' : 1]
```

and call it like `enemy.Goblin.loot.value` but then I get an `unexpected token :`

Comment: what should `enemy.Goblin.loot.value` access? wooden sword or golden coin?

Comment: It's random. It's getting shuffled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array of objects:

```
'loot': [{name: 'a wooden sword', value: 3}, {name: 'a golden coin', value: 1}]
```

Then you can access it like that:

```
enemy.Goblin.loot[0].value
```

Or alternatively, turn `loot` into an object:

```
'loot': {'a wooden sword': 3, 'a golden coin': 1}
```

Then you can access the value like that:

```
enemy.Goblin.loot["a wooden sword"]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way I can thought like

```
var enemy = {
'Goblin' : {
    'HP' : '20',
    'damage' : '3',
    'loot' : {'a wooden sword':3, 'a golden coin':3}
},
'row2' : {
    'key3' : 'input3',
    'key4' : 'input4'
}
};

enemy.Goblin.loot['a wooden sword'] // will give you 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do this dynamically then one way would be using an Object method like `Object.prototype.setNestedValue()` and what would normally be difficult turns out to be an extremely easy job. OK lets see...

```js
Object.prototype.getNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 1 ? (this[a[0]] !== void 0 && this[a[0]].getNestedValue(...a.slice(1))) : this[a[0]];
};
Object.prototype.setNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 2 ? typeof this[a[0]] === "object" && this[a[0]] !== null ? this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1))
                                                                              : (this[a[0]] = typeof a[1] === "string" ? {} : new Array(a[1]),
                                                                                 this[a[0]].setNestedValue(...a.slice(1)))
                      : this[a[0]] = a[1];
};

var enemy = {
  'Goblin' : {
    'HP' : '20',
    'damage' : '3',
    'loot' : ['a wooden sword','a golden coin']
  },
  'row2' : {
    'key3' : 'input3',
    'key4' : 'input4'
  }
};

enemy.setNestedValue("Goblin","loot",0,"a wooden sword",1);
enemy.setNestedValue("Goblin","loot",1,"a golden coin",3);
console.log(JSON.stringify(enemy,null,2));
```